# Injecting angularFileUpload not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, angular-file-upload

this sound like a simple question but i am a newbie with angular, basicly i want to use AngularFileUpload to upload images on my website, so i did this when i initialize my app:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router'],['angularFileUpload']);
```

before i installed the angularFileUpload module trough npm, so my module is inside node_modules, but i get an error evertyme i start my app

**error:**

Failled to instantiate module due to:

> 'fn' is not a function, got string.

someone know what is happening?

Comment: Is the `angularFileUpload` file loaded properly? Or compiled in the build file? Depends what setup you're working from.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are injecting the modules in a wrong way.

You are inserting two arrays:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router'],['angularFileUpload']);
```

Instead you should insert just one array with all modules:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router','angularFileUpload']);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use bower instead of npm for loading your client side dependencies in AngularJs. There are following steps required to correctly load your module:

1. Download using following bower command

> bower install angular-file-upload

2. Then include this library in the script tag, by providing correct location to minified js.
3. Last inject modules in correct way

var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router','angularFileUpload']);

And that's it. Please let me know if it helped you!